# Why does sending an email take so long?

Tags: c#, email, console-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;

namespace MGR_Backuper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = "D:\\Programy\\WinRAR\\rar.exe";
            string command = "C:\\Users\\Pawel\\Desktop\\Praca magisterska back\\mgrback-%YEAR%-%MONTH%-%DAY%-%HOUR%-%MINUTES%-%SECONDS%.rar";
            string arg = "a \"%FILENAME%\" \"C:\\Users\\Pawel\\Desktop\\Praca magisterska\\*\" -m5 -ep1 -hppasspass -rr5 -inul -r0";
            var t1 = DateTime.Now;
            command = command.Replace("%YEAR%", "" + t1.Year);
            if (t1.Month < 10) command = command.Replace("%MONTH%", "0" + t1.Month);
            else command = command.Replace("%MONTH%", "" + t1.Month);

            if (t1.Day < 10) command = command.Replace("%DAY%", "0" + t1.Day);
            else command = command.Replace("%DAY%", "" + t1.Day);

            if (t1.Hour < 10) command = command.Replace("%HOUR%", "0" + t1.Hour);
            else command = command.Replace("%HOUR%", "" + t1.Hour);

            if (t1.Minute < 10) command = command.Replace("%MINUTES%", "0" + t1.Minute);
            else command = command.Replace("%MINUTES%", "" + t1.Minute);

            if (t1.Second < 10) command = command.Replace("%SECONDS%", "0" + t1.Second);
            else command = command.Replace("%SECONDS%", "" + t1.Second);

            arg = arg.Replace("%FILENAME%", command);
            var t2 = DateTime.Now;
            Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = file;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;

                proc.Start();

                while (!proc.HasExited)
                    Thread.Sleep(50);


            var t3 = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
                mailMsg.To.Add("email@email.com");

                // From
                MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("email@email.com", "Sender");
                mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

                // Subject and Body
                mailMsg.Subject = "MGR";
                mailMsg.Body = "Backup magisterki";
             mailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(command));

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("server.serv.com", 587);
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
                smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
                smtpClient.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue;
                smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()+"\n"); }
            var t4 = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Czas kompresji: \t{0:0.00}s", (t3 - t2).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Czas wysyłania: \t{0:0.00}s", (t4 - t3).TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Czas całkowity: \t{0:0.00}s", (t4 - t1).TotalSeconds);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple program for backing up some data important to me by sending it to my email address. The created archive is around 1.5 MB. Sending email takes about 7-8 minutes. This is not because of bad connection because when I try to send the same file by email program or webmail it takes 5-6 seconds. Why is sending email this way is so slow?

**EDIT :**

I made another test

```
            var ts1 = DateTime.Now;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
            var ts2 = DateTime.Now;
```

and it confirmed that `smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);` is responsible for slowing. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked to see that it's definitely the Email portion that's slow, or could it be the process spawn that archives your files ?

Comment: Yes, just start debugging and step through the code to see what's causing the delay.

Comment: What is being attached?  The size of the attachment will matter.  Since you are not sending async it's waiting for the server to confirm that your request has been submitted successfully I believe

Comment: I checked that sending is responsible (see `DateTime` in code?). The file being attached is 1.5 MB rar archive. It is already stated in my question.

Comment: @Ichibann - Are you sure your network credentials aren't timing out?  You set a very high timeout value.

Comment: Can you step into the framework source to see what exactly it's doing?

Comment: @Mystere Man - There is nothing wrong with my credentials. Email is eventually sent (but it takes a lot of time).

Comment: @Rup - I'll check that later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem, It seems that the SMTP server is doing some kind of checking before sending the mail.

I Solved my problem by sending the mail in async way using a new thread as shown below.

```
private void SendMail(string from, string to)
{
    //your logic to send the mail
}
```

to send the mail in async way.

```
ThreadStart threadStart = delegate() { SendMail(from, to); };
Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: @Ichibann it will send the mail in the background so your app can do other things while it's sending, but because it's the last thing your program does, it's not really going to help in this case...